# Android studio CPU Usage performance tool-understanding the trace

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, cpu-usage, trace

I updated my **android studio to version 1.2**

**[Android studio 1.2](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio12preview2available)**

**Performance tools:** The memory usage window is now included as a tab in the Android runtime window, and there is now a tab for graphing CPU usage as well.

[image]
How to understand the trace file?